# Create a "flag" table that references unique IDs in 3 different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

**Oracle SQL**

I have account IDs in 3 different tables (one column per table). They sometimes repeat within the table's column. Some of the distinct account IDs in Table 1 also appear in Table 2. Some appear in all 3 tables. There is no mutual exclusivity requirement across the tables (i.e - an account ID can appear in any combination of the 3 tables).

For example:

| Account ID (from Table 1) | Account ID (from Table 2) | Account ID (from Table 3) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123451 | 876495 | 456123 |
| 456123 | 943215 | 876495 |
| 876495 |  |  |

I'm trying to create a "flag table" like the following, that indicates the tables that each account ID appears in:

| Account ID (UNION) | Account ID in Table 1? | Account ID in Table 2? | Account ID in Table 3? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123451 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 456123 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 876495 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 943215 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

No preference regarding the boolean returning a zero or NULL.

Comment: And what is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(t1.account_id, t2.account_id, t3.account_id) AS account_id,
       NVL2(t1.account_id, 1, 0) AS in_table1,
       NVL2(t2.account_id, 1, 0) AS in_table2,
       NVL2(t3.account_id, 1, 0) AS in_table3
FROM   table1 t1
       FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2
       ON (t1.account_id = t2.account_id)
       FULL OUTER JOIN table3 t3
       ON (  t1.account_id = t3.account_id
          OR t2.account_id = t3.account_id)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (account_id) AS
SELECT 123451 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 456123 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 876495 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 (account_id) AS
SELECT 943215 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 876495 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table3 (account_id) AS
SELECT 456123 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 876495 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ACCOUNT_ID | IN_TABLE1 | IN_TABLE2 | IN_TABLE3 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 123451 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
> | 456123 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
> | 876495 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
> | 943215 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=7d811e48b99b97828c9a10dec150b26f)*

Comment: This is great - thanks so much. Just one tweak needed. I'm getting duplicate lines in my output. Not sure if it's because of the dupe values in the source tables, or if the dupes are also being generated when the ACCOUNT_ID column is generated in the output. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry - cancel that last request about DISTINCT. I'm clearly a novice over here and didn't realize that I can place "DISTINCT" before "COALESCE". Thanks again!!